# Non case sensitive search for usernames using Swift and Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am writing an app and one feature I am working on is to allow users to search for users in the search bar. At the moment it works, however the search is case sensitive. I was wondering if there is anyway to make the search non-case sensitive? For example, when I did a similar thing in PHP, I would do something like this:

```
$searchTerm = strtolower($searchTerm);
```

I would then compare it to the username converted to lower case too.

Here is the kind of thing I am using right now:

```
var findUsers:PFQuery = PFUser.query()

if !name.isEmpty{
    findUsers.whereKey("username", containsString: name) //name is what the user entered
}
```

Comment: First result from googling "parse.com case insensitive query": https://www.parse.com/questions/case-insensitive-query

Comment: Yes that was the first result I got from doing a google search too... I wanted to see if anyone knows any better ways of doing it than creating separate fields for lowercase.

Comment: A well-formulated SO question will list researched solutions and state why they won't work for the poster. In this case, the link I gave you contains a perfectly reasonable solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for doing a google search for me. I didn't think of that!

Comment: Then surely you found this blog post from parse.com, explaining how to do efficient search on their platform? http://blog.parse.com/2013/03/19/implementing-scalable-search-on-a-nosql-backend/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using contains string use matchesRegex: "(?i)(name)"